# Is there a nicer way to write this linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Asset` entities, and each `Asset` has a list of `Field` entities with two properties each that looks like this

`| Index | Value   |`
`|   0   | "hello" |`
`|   1   | "blah"  |`
`|   2   | null    |`

and in a loop I get variables

`i = 2` and `i = 3`

and I have a linq query to try and get the following: `Assets` that have a `Field` where the `Value` corresponding to `i` is `null`, or there is no `Field` with an `Index` `i`.

For example, if `i` is 2, it will return the asset that has the table above, because it has a `Field` where 2 corresponds to `null`.

And, if `i` is 3, it should also return the above because there is no `Field` with `Index` 3.

This code works:

```
var assets = (from a in assets where 
              a.Fields.Any(x => x.Index == i && x.Value == null) select a)
     .Union(from a in assets where 
              a.Fields.All(x => x.Index != i) select a)
     .ToList();
```

This isn't very nice, and I'm wondering is there a way to do it in one statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers work, but if you simplify the question it gets even more straightforward:

```
assets.Where(a => !a.Fields().Any(f => f.Index == i &&
                                       f.Value != null))
      .ToList()
```

You want all the `Asset`s where there isn't a `Field` with an `Index` of `i` and a non-null `Value`. You don't need to split that into two conditions.

Comment: Murphy's law, I give the same answer 30 seconds beforehand just using the inverse logic and Andrew gets all the points!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need two queries, just use one with an `||`:

```
assets = assets
    .Where(a => a.Fields.Any(f => f.Index == i && f.Value == null)
            ||  a.Fields.All(f => f.Index != i))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, as I see it:

1. use a more traditional JOIN syntax of LINQ and LEFT JOIN only on the Asset ID and Index.  So if the LEFT JOIN returns null (i.e. `DefaultIfEmpty()`) then that index wasn't found for that Asset.  That's case #2.  However, if it is NOT null, then you can filter (i.e. `where` clause) further by checking that `Value` is `null`.  That's case #1.
2. You can combine where statement.  `where a.Fields.Any(...) || a.Fields.All`.

You would want to try them both, in my opinion, to see which performs better for your needs.  I'd guess the first option would perform much better, but if the data size is small, the second option is definitely much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
var assets = assets.where(a => a.Fields.Any(x => x.Index == i && x.Value == null) || a.Fields.All(x => x.Index != i)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually shortcut the query a bit in this case

```
 var assets = (
                from a in assets
                where a.Fields.All(x => x.Index != i || x.Value == null)
                select a
              ).ToList();
```